# Is the grid visible in an animation?

Tags: animation

I saw a bunch of question talking about the grid object type. I'm not talking about that, I'm talking about the "web" that can not be selected.

Now that we have that out of the way, here is my question.

I'm trying to make a 2d desktop animation, and it is working out pretty well so far, but I'm worried that the "grid" will be visible in the final product. Do I have to worry about this?

Answer (score 1):

No the grid is a visual guide, part of the viewport and won't show up anywhere else except the OpenGL rendering.

Unless you are planning on doing some simplistic OpenGL based rendering this should never be a problem.

If you do use the *Render OpenGL viewport* and it does show up, remember to tick the option *Render Only* in the 3DView Properties Shelf, under the *Shading* tab.